# What are the possible dimensions of $N(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $f$ is linear functional on an n-dimensional vector space $V$ then what are the possible dimensions of $N(f)$ i.e. Nullity of $f$.

If $V$ is a vector space over $K$ and $f:V\mapsto K$ then $N(f)$is a subspace of $V$ .Also $N(f)+R(f)=V$ where $R(f)$ is range of $f$. So $N(f)$ has all possibilities such that $0\leq N(f)\leq \dim V$.

But the answer is $n-1$  or $n$ .Why is this true? Please help.

Comment: By the definition of a linear functional, $R(f) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is because the dimension of the range is $\le 1$.

Comment: Why can't $K=\Bbb C$ @angryavian;@crostul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nullity of a linear *map* from $V$ to some other vector space (possibly $V$ itself again) can indeed be anything less than the dimension of $V$. However, "functional" usually means "linear map from $V$ to $k$," that is, the field of scalars (viewed as a 1-dimensional vector space over itself); probably in your context this means $V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Now, the nullity has to be "big" since the target space is "small". A good exercise: Suppose $f: V\rightarrow W$ is linear, $V$ has dimension $n$, $W$ has dimension $m$. What do we know about the nullity of $f$?

Comment: Why can't $K=\Bbb C$?

Comment: @Amartya It totally can (or any other field); I was just guessing. But the field of scalars is always one-dimensional over itself: $\mathbb{C}$ is a one-dimensional complex vector space (even though we usually think of it as a *two*-dimensional *real* vector space), $\mathbb{R}$ is a one-dimensional real vector space, etc. No matter what your field of scalars is, it's a one-dimensional vector space over itself.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $K$ can be regarded as a $1$-dimensional vector space over itself, meaning that the range $R(f) \subseteq K$ is either a zero or one dimensional subspace of $K$. This means the map has rank one or zero, from which the claim follows.